# Join to a table that its name is in a row result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables called comment, admin, user.

comment:

```
body             userType            userId
--------------------------------------------
comment1         admin               1
comment2         user                2
```

admin:

```
id             title
-----------------------
1              amir        
2              farhad
```

user:

```
id             title
-----------------------
1              kazem        
2              ali
```

I want to get the comment and userTypes' title from it's table by one query like:

```
SELECT u.title, c.body FROM comment c, c.userType u
```

but it doesn't work!

Comment: Please provide the structure of all three tables.

Comment: That query isn't valid SQL. As per the above comments, please provide all three table structures

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @SEarle1986 comment and it's user title. userType is the users table.

Comment: So who is user id 4? they're not in the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple options come to mind:

using a union:

```
SELECT title, body FROM comment c JOIN user u on c.userId = u.id and userType = 'user'
UNION
SELECT title, body FROM comment c JOIN admin u on c.userId = u.id and userType = 'admin'
```

using left joins:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(u.title, a.title) as title,
  c.body 
FROM comment c 
  LEFT JOIN user u on c.userId = u.id and userType = 'user'
  LEFT JOIN user a on a.userId = u.id and userType = 'admin'
WHERE COALESCE(u.title, a.title) is not null;
```

This uses ANSI SQL `COALESCE`. If you are using T-SQL (MS SQL), you will need to use `ISNULL` instead.

More generically, this is a case of [the "Concrete Table Inheritance" pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html), and the `userType` column is called a *discriminator*.

Comment: if i had id column for comment, how can i add order by c.id for union?

Comment: I believe you can append `ORDER BY c.id` to the query, but that may not work with a `union`. You may have to include the comment ID with an alias in the `SELECT` clause and then order by that alias.

e.g. `SELECT title, body, c.id as comment_id … ORDER BY comment_id`